# how do I find out what program's on the other end of a local socket?

Tags: linux, debugging, sockets

A process on my Linux system, strace tells me, is talking on a socket which has file descriptor 10. lsof tells me that this is a unix socket with inode 11085, and netstat further tells me that inode 11085 a stream socket, and that it's connected.

Given that this process doesn't have any other threads, there must therefore be another process on the system that's connected to the other end of this socket. How do I find out what it is?

**Update:**

There's some illumination from the lsof author [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090608083420/http://www.justskins.com/forums/lsof-find-both-endpoints-of-a-unix-socket-123037.html). Essentially, it seems that Linux just doesn't provide this information.

Comment: A process can own both ends of a socket even if there are no threads.

Comment: True. But in this case, it's poll()ing the socket and waking up periodically, so there must be something else waking it up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ss -p
```

will tell. (Provided the socket is not owned by the kernel itself.)

Comment: On Debian, `/usr/bin/ss` is in the `iproute2` package

Comment: This didn't help in my case, but marking as correct since it's simple and works well for IP and unix sockets.

Comment: The question was about local sockets. -1

Comment: Bad I cannot give you two stars. This problem has been challenging me since months... Now I can complete my guide http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Strace

Answer (score 7):

Does `netstat -p` help ?

From Manpage:

```
  -p,
  --program Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is busybox netstat, so it doesn't support -p. But node 11085 only turns up in the netstat output once anyway, so it seems that it only belongs to the process I already know about.

Comment: @daf you should mention the use of busybox in your question (and maybe in a tag, too)

Comment: Busybox does have a configuration option to support the `-p` switch. See option `CONFIG_FEATURE_NETSTAT_PRG`, selected in busybox menuconfig via **Networking Utilities → netstat → Enable PID/Program name output**.

Answer (score 5):

How about this: `grep 11085 /proc/net/unix`. Assuming there is a non-empty path present on the line with the  inode you're interested in, `grep` for that path in `/proc/net/unix` to find the the inode for the other end of the connection, then use @efficientjelly's method to map the other inode to a `pid`.

A key point here is the fact that the two connected sockets will each have a different inode number.

Comment: Cunning! I didn't know about /proc/net/unix. Sadly, there isn't a path associated with this socket.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you have no luck with the appropriate lsof and netstat options, you can also do the following:

```
find /proc -lname '*11085*' 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Cunning! As the system only has busybox find, -lname doesn't work, but we can emulate it:

$ for i in `find /proc -type l`; do readlink "$i" | grep -q 11085 && echo "$i"; done
/proc/1892/task/1892/fd/10
/proc/1892/fd/10

So, only the original process comes up.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like if you're really desperate, you can get that information directly from Linux kernel memory by using some kernel debugger. With RHEL5's "crash" tool:

- get uncompressed `vmlinux` image (eg. install `kernel-debuginfo` rpm, or extract `vmlinux` file from that rpm)
- run `crash /path/to/vmlinux`
- `net -s 12345` lists all sockets for `PID` 12345
- find the interesting socket (has to be of family/type `UNIX:STREAM`), and note its `SOCK` value:

  - `PID: 12345   TASK: e903d000  CPU: 0   COMMAND: "someapp"`
  - `FD   SOCKET     SOCK    FAMILY:TYPE          SOURCE-PORT      DESTINATION-PORT`
  - `36  cadd0240  c8a64040  UNIX:STREAM`
- you now have the address of the `unix_sock struct` for this socket

  - basically, `unix_sock.peer.name` is the name structure of the other end of the socket
  - print it with:`p *(*(*((struct unix_sock*)( (struct unix_sock*)0xc8a64040)->peer)).addr).name`

Really sad that this information is not directly exported to userspace.

Answer (score 2):

I have observed that :

Inode of the `fd` that called `connect()` on the client side, is always exactly one greater than the one that you got back from the `accept()` call on the server side.

Example output from my prog:

```
client_fd=4
/proc/4436/fd/4
inode=3072
is socket
node: 3072 socket: /tmp/unix.socket
f0be8960: 00000003 00000000 00000000 0001 03  3072 /tmp/unix.socket

/proc/9293/fd/43
fd:43
inode=3073
is socket
node: 3073 socket: 
f0be81e0: 00000003 00000000 00000000 0001 03  3073
```

The bound path does not show in `/proc/net/unix` though.

YMMV and i have not investigated the underlying mechanics.

Comment: +1, unfortunately it looks like the only way to get a result ... !

Comment: (sorry, I was too fast to comment, that's not verified on my computer...)

Comment: Works most of the time, but not reliable (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26932730/1883178))

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [tool](https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/unix_sockets_peers) which uses the [gdb method](https://serverfault.com/a/417946/148210) to reliably get socket peer information, kernel debug symbols not needed.

To get the process connected to a given socket, pass it the inode number:

```
# socket_peer 11085
3703 thunderbird
```

To find out for all processes at once use `netstat_unix`, it adds a column to netstat's output:

```
# netstat_unix
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Peer PID/Program name  Path
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6825     982/Xorg             1497/compiz            /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6824     1497/compiz          982/Xorg                 
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONNECTED     207142   3770/chromium-brows  17783/UMA-Session-R       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     204903   1523/pulseaudio      3703/thunderbird       
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     204902   3703/thunderbird     1523/pulseaudio           
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     204666   1523/pulseaudio      3703/thunderbird       
...
```

Try `netstat_unix --dump` if you need output that's easy to parse.
See https://github.com/lemonsqueeze/unix_sockets_peers for details.

For info, the [inode +1/-1 hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834657/1883178) isn't reliable. It works most of the time but will fail or (worse) return the wrong socket if you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>lsof | grep 11085</strike>

lsof should be executed as root.

I've been experimenting with lsof on my Linux system and `lsof -U` shows that all the numbers under the column NODE are unique.