# How to find out what the socket points to?

Tags: linux, sockets, process

I have a lot of opened sockets for one of the processes in the system (RHEL):

```
$ls -1l /proc/22794/fd | less
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 201 -> socket:[1662944133]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 202 -> socket:[1662944193]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 203 -> socket:[1684299114]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 204 -> socket:[1662944920]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 205 -> socket:[1662987275]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 206 -> socket:[1663104470]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 207 -> socket:[1663067786]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 208 -> socket:[1663045536]
lrwx------ 1 myapp apps 64 Jun  8 14:53 209 -> socket:[1663233730]
```

...

I know exactly what the process is it. I need to know where the sockets, which were created by these known process, point to.

Would you be so kind as to tell me, how can I find out what each socket points to?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With root's id, you see the program-to-socket connection with `netstat -p`.

Comment: You can use `lsof -p $pid | grep IPv` to list the open connections.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
netstat -napev
```

might shed some light.

Comment: Thank you, but I know exactly what the process is it. I need to know where the sockets, which were created by these known process, point to.

Comment: @semiliranda what exactly do you mean by `point to`? this command shows you all open sockets, with information about them, you can grep for your process ID. what else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

`netstat -nap` will list all open sockets for each running process, run it with root priviledges.

Comment: Thank you, but I know exactly what the process is it. I need to know where the sockets, which were created by these known process, point to.

Comment: Did you even try the command?, That's what `netstat` do, list information about sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [how do I find out what program's on the other end of a local socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820782/how-do-i-find-out-what-programs-on-the-other-end-of-a-local-socket/4834881#4834881)

The answer is

```
ss -p | grep <socket-number>
```